# Formtastic Confused on Has One Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I'm a bit stuck on a 'has_one' and 'belongs_to' relationship and getting it to properly display in Formtastic. I have a person model that has one picture (a profile picture). I want the user to be able to select the picture using radio buttons. So far, I have:

```
<% form.inputs do %>
  <%= form.input :picture, :as => :radio, :collection => @pictures %>
<% end %>
```

However, this fails (because the foreign key is stored on the 'belongs_to' side of associations in Rails. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using custom controller code to fix. Use a variety of filters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this in the "related" sidebar. I think this is a good use case for nested attributes -- from the Formtastic README:

> Nested forms are also supported (don’t forget your models need to be setup correctly
>   with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`). You can do it in the Rails way:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @post do |form| %>
  <%= form.inputs :title, :body, :created_at %>
  <%= form.semantic_fields_for :author do |author| %>
   <%= author.inputs :first_name, :last_name, :name => "Author" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

> Or the Formtastic way with the :for option:

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @post do |form| %>
   <%= form.inputs :title, :body, :created_at %>
   <%= form.inputs :first_name, :last_name, :for => :author, :name => "Author" %>
   <%= form.buttons %>
<% end %>
```